# Can Google Apps Scripts be flexible enough to handle multiple sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sites

Is it possible with one Google Apps Script published as a Web Application to be flexible enough to connect to different spreadsheets depending on the person or webmaster using the Application?

I saw when working with one of my scripts there are ‘script properties’ and then ‘user properties’ tabs under ‘Project properties’.

I tried to add a property but couldn't get it to Stick

So then I found Google Apps Script ‘Class Properties’ area.

When I think of how these two properties might work, I think of Google Gadgets. A user can add a gadget to her Google Site but can then change or configure the Gadget in the properties area of that gadget

Is this type of functionality possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure settings that will allow one script to access the files of the user of the Apps Script.  The user needs to log in with their Google account.
You can publish the Apps Script script to run as ANYONE, and **Execute the app as:** *User Accessing the Web App*.  Which requires the user to log in with their Google Account, and will allow the script to access the users files.

The **Properties Service** is for storage.  It doesn't set or grant permissions. A break down comparison of the different types of Properties is shown at:

[Comparison of Property Stores](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#comparison_of_property_stores)

Comment: Sandy, so I think you are saying that I could code a script.  Publish it as a web application and send you the web application url only; not the script code. Somehow I could allow you to Execute the application as you and you would somehow be able to add your spreadsheet being able to read  and write data. I could then send the same exact url that I sent you to another person  and that person could then  Execute the application as him and he could add his own spreadsheet to read and write data to.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes, that's all correct.  One url, each person signing in with their Google account, and the script accessing their Drive.  They'd need to authorized permission the first time.

Comment: Sandy, I wanted to let you know that I am working on the "You can publish the Apps Script script to run as ANYONE, and Execute the app as: User Accessing the Web App. "   I have been able to create a spreadsheet with code using my developer login so I think I am close to a successful test. So far my non developer login I can see the user interface after the authorization but no new spreadsheet yet.

Answer (score 2):

For the question, 'Can Google Script me modified to run differently depending on who's running it', yes.

For example, you could use the function '[getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())', and dependent on who the user was, you could set a variable such as 'thisUsersSheet == usersSpreadsheet key', among many other ways to do this.

Whether or not it would be possible to have it replaced site gadgets, that's much more dependent on what you're trying to achieve specifically.

Note: You mention '[Script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties)' and '[User Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/user-properties)' in your question. Stay away from these, they are deprecated.

Comment: HDCerberus, I'm trying to wrap my head around what you are saying...  Initially I didn't see your answer sorry... I hope you also look at the comment that I added to Sandy's post.  So if you can't use properties of some sort then I can't grasp how a person could get the usersSpreadsheet key without giving them the code so that they can insert it into that code. I am hoping you can help me understand.

Comment: Your best bet is to refer to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties, as I'm not going to be able to go in depth into how you can customize your script to each person, that will have to be something you figure out yourself. :/